# Neglecting HTTP Post request headers when read using BufferedReader

Tags: java, http

I am currently listening on a port using BufferedReader like:

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(2346);

Socket s = ss.accept();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
while(true){
    inputLine = in.readLine();
    if(inputLine==null)
       break;
}
```

Now I am getting all the headers and everything like:

```
POST /record HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Length: 1969
Host: localhost:2346
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">...
```

The problem is that I need just the content of the POST request(the last line above), so is there a Java parser that could do it. And in my request to the socket I need to give an extra empty line to allow it to be read properly. Is there a solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response body is always separated by one blank line from the response header. You can either write your own parser or use a library like HttpCore http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/

Comment: Thanks I used the idea of the blank line. I wasn't sure it was always there. And do you know how I can change my loop so that I don't have to always add a blank like in my request?

Comment: @OVB HTTP is specified so as to separate the headers from the body by a blank line. If you're writing all this yourself you are *obliged* to send the blank line. If you're using `HttpURLConnection` it will send the blank line automatically.

Comment: Hi Alexander, although your answer is the accepted answer, is it possible for you to show an example so it's more clear to future users who visit this page? This will help other visitors to this page, and will meet StackOverflow's goal of being a resource of knowledge for years to come. Good luck! :)